# Dreamweaver CC cannot set up server for PHP files

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I was using Dreamweaver CS6 before, and I can test my PHP files in it(just to create a site and indicating the server root, etc, and everything is ready). But in CC version, I did the same thing, exactly the same setting as CS6, but my PHP file cannot be shown. I clicked the "connect to remote server" icon, and it cannot be connected(the icon cannot be on).

What's wrong with the CC version???

Answer (score 1):

take a look to this links, this will help you...
[helpx.adobe](http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/sites-dialog-box-options.html)
[tv.adobe](http://tv.adobe.com/en/watch/learn-dreamweaver-cs4/getting-started-08-managing-and-uploading-sites/)
[blogs.adobe](http://blogs.adobe.com/dreamweaver/2013/06/dreamweaver-cc-your-all-in-one-tool-for-creating-publishing-and-managing-websites-and-mobile-content.html)